# Any way to install xcode on old 2007 Macbook Pro (64 bit machine)?

Tags: xcode

Hello I'm interested in developing apps in swift but current xcode download requires Mac OS 10.13.6. I have a 2007 Macbook Pro currently with OS 10.9.5. EveryMac.com shows maximum OS for my machine 10.11.x but does not automatically install when I check for software updates.

Any suggestions for finding an older verison of xcode compatible with Mac OS 10.9 or 10.11? Should I try to run a virtual machine instead?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To get 10.11.x see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Answer (score 0):

You can download older versions of XCode from the [Apple Developers Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). If you don't have an Apple Developer account, you can create one for free by visiting the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) site.

I'm not sure what your goal is, but with an old version of XCode, you won't be able to make anything for the recent versions of iOS, watchOS, macOS, tvOS, or use the most recent version of Swift.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the info. For now I just want to code the underlying math for an app and see how it runs. I've got basic parameters worked on out a spreadsheet but now I need to automate with some code. I've thought about coding in Python to get started but eventually want it available for Apple products so I need to learn Swift one way or another.